# Pentaho - Spoon 4.1.0 Import/Export repository - Jobs and translations

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, xbmc

As described in the title, I would like to import all my jobs and translations from my integration to the validation environment. I saw that in higher versions (4.1.0 is my actual version) there are two options available: Tools --> "Export repository..." and "Import repository...", but these do not exist in this version.

Import\Export for version higher than 4.1.0 : http://pldwh.blogspot.fr/2013/02/pentaho-data-integration-exportimport.html

To Export, I found out a tutorial:
I have already exported all my jobs and transformations into two XML files by creating a job and using the component "Export repository to XML file".

Export with a job: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Export+repository+to+XML+file

Now, I need to import these files into the integration environment.

Could you give some information about this step?

Thank you in advance for your help